# Git: Add Submodule from Another Branch

Tags: git

An issue I am having with my project is in one branch (`BRANCH1`), I added 2 submodules (`MOD1`, `MOD2`). Now `BRANCH1` has been put on hold.

Now that I am working on `BRANCH2`, I would like **only** the submodules (the rest of the changes are not ready yet). How would I add `MOD1` and `MOD2` to my current branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a single commit on `BRANCH1` whose sole effect was adding one (or both) submodules, then you can `git cherry-pick` that commit (or those commits, if you added the submodules in separate commits) onto `BRANCH2`. If the submodule additions were done as part of a bigger commit that you don't want the rest of, you can use `git cherry-pick --no-commit`, then clean out the changes you don't want before committing. Or you could always just run the appropriate `git submodule add` commands on `BRANCH2` (which may or may not result in a fresh `clone` of the submodules - I can't say I've ever run into that situation, so I don't know for sure...).

Comment: In my case, since I knew I had the most up to date version of both, so a fresh clone would not cause any issues. I simply ran "git submodule add." In both cases, git printed out "Adding existing repo at 'FolderName' to the index." So far, no problems.